# Improper Integral Calculation with Lots of Constants

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have an improper integral:

$$T=4\sqrt{m}\int_0^\sqrt{2E/k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E-kx^2}}dx$$

I said it was improper because if you plug in the upper bound, I believe the denominator = 0.
I am supposed to evaluate to show that:

$$T=2\pi\sqrt{m/k}$$

I am just not even sure how to start, any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Try the substitution $x=\sqrt{\dfrac{2E}{k}}\sin t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to rewrite it this way : Let's keep $4\sqrt{m}$ away for a moment :

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2E/k}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E-kx^2}}}dx
&=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2E/k}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-kx^2/2E}}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2E/k}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-[(\sqrt{k/2E})x]^2}}dx}
\end{align}
If we dentoe $\alpha=\sqrt{k/2E}$ then we'll have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\int_{0}^{1/\alpha}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\alpha x)^2}}dx}$$

Which is the $Arcsin$ primitive :
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\int_{0}^{1/\alpha}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\alpha x)^2}}dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\Bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha}arcsin(\alpha x)\Bigg]_0^\frac{1}{\alpha}$$
Which yields :
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\Bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha}arcsin(\alpha x)\Bigg]_0^\frac{1}{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\Bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha}arcsin(1)-\frac{1}{\alpha}arcsin(0)\Bigg]$$

Since $arcsin(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $arcsin(0)=0$, and by replacing $\alpha$ with $\sqrt{k/2E}$, we get
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2E/k}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E-kx^2}}}dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k/2E}}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\sqrt{\frac{2E}{k}}\frac{\pi}{2}$$
We are left with
$$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k}}$$
By multiplying by the $4\sqrt{m}$ left at the begining, we finally get :
$$T=4\sqrt{m}\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k}}=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$